# Append tbody td to th based on similar index

Tags: javascript, jquery

i'm trying to append tbody td with the similar to thead th with the similar index.

```js
$("table").find("th").each(function(i, e) {
  console.log(i, e)
  $(this).attr('head-index', i)
});

$("table").find("td").each(function(i, e) {
  console.log(i, e)
  $(this).attr('row-index', i)
});

var tableTH = $("table > thead > tr > th");
var tableTR = $("table > tbody > tr > td");

if ($(tableTH).attr == $(tableTR).attr) {

} else {

}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table table-hover">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Content 1 Head</th>
      <th>Content 2 Head</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Content 1</td>
      <td>Content 2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Content 4</td>
      <td>Content 5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Content 7</td>
      <td>Content 8</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

This function will be triggered in mobile view only.

End Result expected.

[image]

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9esef.png)

*Edited(What is there's more TR)

Comment: What is `if ($(tableTH).attr == $(tableTR).attr)` supposed to mean? `.attr` is a function, but you're not calling it. What attribute are you trying to compare?

Comment: Don't make up custom attributes like `head-index` and `row-index`. Use `.data()` to associate custom values with DOM elements.

Comment: You can't append a `td` to a `th`. They both need to be children of `tr`.

Comment: i am trying to compare the thead th and tbody td, with the similar index. 
then, it would be great if i could append the thead th with tbody td with the similar index.

Comment: Your end result looks like each `<th>` and `<td>` is in a different `<tr>`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.each()` to loop over the headers, and an attribute selector to select get the row with the same index.

```js
$("table").find("th").each(function(i, e) {
  $(this).attr('head-index', i)
});

$("table").find("td").each(function(i, e) {
  $(this).attr('row-index', i)
});

var tableTH = $("table > thead > tr > th");
var tableTR = $("table > tbody > tr > td");

tableTH.each(function() {
  var index = $(this).attr("head-index");
  var row = tableTR.filter(`[row-index=${index}]`);
  $(this).after(row);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table table-hover">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Content 1 Head</th>
      <th>Content 2 Head</th>
      <th>Content 3 Head</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Content 1</td>
      <td>Content 2</td>
      <td>Content 3</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

I used `.after()` rather than `.append()`. You can't append a `<td>` inside a `<th>`, they both have to be children of `<tr>`.

Answer (score 0):

Is this you are trying to achieve?

```js
$(function(){
  var th = $("table > thead > tr > th");
  var td = $("table > tbody > tr > td");

  $('thead tr').each(function(th_index,th_item) {
    var index = $(th_item).attr("data-th-index");
    var row = $('tbody tr[data-td-index="'+index+'"]');
    row.each(function(td_index,td_item){
      $(th_item).after(td_item);
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table table-hover">
      <thead>
        <tr data-th-index="1">
          <th>Content 1 Head</th>
          </tr>
          <tr data-th-index="2">
          <th >Content 2 Head</th>
                    </tr>
          <tr data-th-index="3">
          <th >Content 3 Head</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr data-td-index="1">
          <td >Content 1</td>
          </tr>
          <tr data-td-index="2">
          <td >Content 2</td>
                    </tr>
          <tr data-td-index="3">
          <td >Content 3</td>
                    </tr>
          <tr data-td-index="1">
          <td >Content 5</td>
                    </tr>
          <tr data-td-index="2">
          <td >Content 6</td>
                    </tr>
          <tr data-td-index="3">
          <td >Content 7</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply, but nope. I will post a new question.

Answer (score 0):

1. Use `$.each` on all `TD`s
2. If `index` is even number then add first `th`(Head 1)
3. If `index` is odd number then add second `th`(Head 2)
4. Append string and create new table

```js
var new_table_string="";
$.each($("table tbody tr td"), function (index,value){
    console.log(value);
    var tdval= $(this).html()
    new_table_string += "<tr><th>" + $("table thead tr th").eq(index%2).html() + "</th></tr><tr><td>" + tdval + "</td></tr>";
});
//$("table").empty();
$(".table2").append(new_table_string);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Before:
<table class="table table-hover" border="1">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Content 1 Head</th>
      <th>Content 2 Head</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Content 1</td>
      <td>Content 2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Content 3</td>
      <td>Content 4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Content 5</td>
      <td>Content 6</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Content 7</td>
      <td>Content 8</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
After:
<table class="table2" border="1"></table>
```